# how do i get a lower time complexity with a nested loop

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, time, complexity-theory

Hi everyone i'm working on c and my code looks like this, basically it's an array and in every array[j] there is a number from 1 to 8, not in order and i'm trying to find where 1 is, and do some operations, then find 2 and do other operations etc.. till number 8:

```
for(i=1;i<9;i++)
   for(j=0;j<8;j++)
     if(array[j]==i)
       //and operations to do but they are not needed now;
```

I'm trying to find another way of doing this with less time spent in the cycle as the complexity can be (n^2). Someone advided me a hasing system to order things but i don't know if it's good enough.
Thanks to everyone!

Comment: I'm not sure we have enough information to really answer this. What is the problem size? Do different instances of the problem have numbers other than 8, or is the number 8 fixed?

Comment: no the problem does not have a fixed size, basically i have an array of structs, the struct is like this typedef struct {int index; char*string}. And i have to print the strings in order as the struct.index is a casual number from 1 to n. With the nested loop it takes too much time to print everything. In case i have n=1000 the worst case will take O(n*n) complexity and it's too much!

Comment: so, do you want a faster execution or do you want less O complexity?

Comment: stackoverflow is not here to design your code.  Please post a [mcve] and what you want to improve

Comment: less time complexity means faster execution in the worst cases, right? anyway what i needed was a less complexity way of doing the same thing and still wasn't able to find it

Answer (score 3):

[Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) has an average complexity of O(n log(n)).
Sort the pair (value, index) by index so you can access them in O(1).

```
struct pair
{
    int val;
    int index;
};

int pair_compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
    struct pair* x = (struct pair*)a;
    struct pair* y = (struct pair*)b;

    return x->val > y->val;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[8] = {4,2,1,3,6,5,8,7};
    
    struct pair* pairs = (struct pair*) calloc(8, sizeof(*pairs));

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        pairs[i].val = arr[i];
        pairs[i].index = i;
    }

    qsort(pairs, 8, sizeof(*pairs), pair_compare);

    for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
    {
        printf("val: %d\tindex: %d\n", pairs[i].val, pairs[i].index);
    }

    free(pairs);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: qsort the array is slower than just iterate over it, so if there's no need to get the array sorted, it's better and less complex to just use a for loop as done in the og question

Comment: Are you saying that the time complexity of two nested for loops is smaller than qsort's?

Comment: No, but if he sorts each array, he will use a qsort inside a for loop, I'm saying that iterating over each array is less complex than sorting each array

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood the question!

Answer (score 0):

suggest the code have an outer loop going through the arrays of 8 structs

For each array of 8 structs, loop through that 8, placing the index into that array of structs into a separate array of 8 integers according to the value in the first field of each struct.

Then a loop that goes through that array of 8 offsets, one by one, performing the desired operation for that specified struct instance.